# Select all labels inside a form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My problem is that i want to select all labels inside a form and remove a certain class.

What i have now is something like this:

```
<form id="frmCreateCase" name="frmCreateCase">
    <div id="radioSubjectName" class="radioButtons">
        <input type="radio" value="Information" id="radioSubjectName1" name="radioSubjectName" /><label for="radioSubjectName1">Information</label>
        <input type="radio" value="Sales" id="radioSubjectName2" name="radioSubjectName" /><label for="radioSubjectName2">Sales</label>
    </div>
    <div id="radioProductName" class="radioButtons">
        <input type="radio" value="WP" id="radioProductName1" name="radioProductName" /><label for="radioProductName1">WP</label>
        <input type="radio" value="FST" id="radioProductName2" name="radioProductName" /><label for="radioProductName2">FST</label>
    </div>
    <div id="radioStatusName" class="radioButtons">
        <input type="radio" value="STARTED" id="radioStatusName1" name="radioStatusName" /><label for="radioStatusName1">STARTED</label>
        <input type="radio" value="AWAITING REVIEW" id="radioStatusName2" name="radioStatusName" /><label for="radioStatusName2">AWAITING REVIEW</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then i initialize my button set to have nice looking buttons like this

```
$( "#radioSubjectName" ).buttonset();
etc.....
```

When clicked, these labels receive class 'ui-state-active'.

I want to create a functionality to loop all the labels and remove that class from each label.
What i do now is something like this:

```
$("label[for='radioSubjectName1']").removeClass('ui-state-active');
$("label[for='radioSubjectName2']").removeClass('ui-state-active');
etc...
```

Is there an easier way to loop all these labels that are child to my form and do this removal of class?

Comment: Does your method not work, or are you just looking for a different way to do this?

Comment: I am looking for an easier way

Comment: Thanks all for your answers! I have replaced some 30 lines of js with just 1 line of JQuery!!! That's something!

Comment: So which variant did you go for in the end? which was faster easier to remember

Comment: I used the accepted answer. I haven't profiled the code in terms of performance. For 30 labels i don't think it makes a noticeable difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about

```
$('form#frmCreateCase label.ui-state-active').removeClass('ui-state-active')
```

this will remove these classes from the ones that have it.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Sorry yes that would remove it from all forms, i have edited it so it only does the one in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$("#frmCreateCase label").removeClass("ui-state-active");`

Answer (score 1):

the fastest is likely to be:

```
$("#frmCreateCase").find("label.ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-state-active");
```